# Commerce and Views - show all products where there are colours available as different clickable links

Tags: views, commerce

I am building a commerce site. I'm trying to create a view where all my products will show with image, title and price. I sell t-shirts in say 3 different colours in 3 different sizes. In the overview page I want to show the 3 colours as separate items not as being part of the same listing. when I create a view it will come up either as all the options, so the same colour 3 times, one for each size or I can create it that just one colour comes up representing the full article. Can someone explain how I can create what I am trying to achieve?

Thank you very much,
Peter